# Properly printing a character depending on a variable using python

Tags: python, variables, optimization, printing, sign

I'd like to know if there was a good pythonic way to do something like this:

```
size1 = 4 
size2 = 3
value = size1 - size2

def isSign(value):
    if value > 0 :
        return "+"
    else :
        return ""

print("My total gain is" + isSign(value) + str(value))
```

In this case my string should look like this:

```
My total gain is +1
```

In a case where value is -1 my string should look like this:

```
My total gain is -1
```

In a case where value is 0 my string should look like this:

```
My total gain is 0
```

I'd also like to avoid extern modules if possible.

Comment: @MoxieBall but that gives `+0` which is not desired. I think your answer was good, you should undelete it.

Comment: @AlexHall didn't catch that, deleting dup suggestion. And I'll undelete it, just so that an fstrings way is on the record

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace `isSign(value)` with `(value > 0) * "+"`.

This works because `True == 1` and `False == 0`, and a number `n` times a string is that string repeated `n` times, so `0 * "+"` is the empty string `""`.

However, some may find it unreadable, as evidenced by the fact that I have to explain how it works.

Using an f-string:

```
f"My total gain is {(value > 0) * '+'}{value}"
```

Comment: So "multiplying" a string with a boolean decides to wether or not print it? Interesting! 
Thanks

Comment: @GaëtanGOUSSEAUD no, this isn't about printing, it's about the strings. Multiplying produces a new string which may or may not be empty.

Comment: I actually was writing before you edited the post for further understanding x). You were very informative, thank you!

Comment: I tagged this answer as the one that helped me because I am actually using python 2.7 and fstrings doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

f-strings are a good way to do this:

```
print(f'My total gain is {"+" if value > 0 else ""}{value}')
```

Comment: Much more pedagogic indeed, it's interesting to have both I believe.

Answer (score 4):

String formatting provides a `+` flag for this:

```
>>> "{:+}".format(3)
'+3'
>>> "{:+}".format(-3)
'-3'
```

Comment: Well, that's annoying.